# Finding a reaction from a KEGG map

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, database, pathway

I have come across a [map](http://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?map01200) and a part of it looks like this: 
[image] 
Now I have not been able to locate the reaction that converts alpha D-Glucose to Glucono-1,5-lactone but was successfully able to locate the [reaction](http://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?R01786) that converts alpha D-glucose Glucose to Glucose-6P. Since an arrow exist from alpha D-Glucose to Glucono-1,5-lactone, i am assuming that such a reaction exist. But could not locate it. I clicked on the arrow marked in blue in the picture, but could not find the desired reaction.(alpha D glucose and beta D glucose are different compounds)  What is the reaction and how is it possible to find the reaction from the map?
NB: The arrows are clickable so are the circles that denote the compound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a simple search. You could have easily searched for glucose oxidase in KEGG, and you would have got [this reaction](http://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?reaction+R01522).

In fact if you had clicked the link for glucunolactone's [*compound* page](http://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?C00198), you would have got a list of many different reactions that convert glucose to glucunolactone.

You can even click the arrow which opens the *KEGG-ORTHOLOGY* page. You can find a field called *RN* in the section called "Other DBs". The links corresponding to this field would give you the exact reactions, that the pathway uses.